# Wordpress Theme Optimization

Tags: wordpress, optimization, themes

I would like to find out the sections of my WordPress theme which are slowing the websites down, is there a plugin which can give me a show me each action preformed and the speed.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use a plugin to find out where your site is being slowed down. I would run and SEO analysis on it (you can find them on a lot of seo companies sites - or just look it up) That will tell you if you are using irrelevant JS. If you are you can minimize it. Look for a JS minimister plugin that works well for your theme. Most plugins will be CSS and JS. Alternatively you could write a function so code doesn't execute on load.